# I need help with understanding a probability question regarding cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The probability (at least theoretically) of picking two cards with different denominations is given by $\frac {\binom{13}{2}×\binom{4}{1}^{2}}{\binom {52}{2}}$ if I am not mistaken. Initially however I though that it was $\frac {\binom{13}{1}×\binom{12}{1}×\binom {4}{1}^{2}}{\binom {52}{2}}$. Allow me to explain what I though and hopefully someone can correct me. So there's 13 different  denominations and 4 different cards of the same suit so $\binom{13}{1}×\binom{4}{1}$ ways to pick the first card. For the second card there's 12 remaining denominations, hence $\binom{12}{1}×\binom {4}{1}$ways to pick it. That's how I arrived at my result, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You are double-counting every combination. Say your first card is an Ace and the second is a King. You end up with an AK combo. Say now that the first card is a King and the second an Ace. You still end up with the same combo, but you counted it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing 5 diamond then 6 heart is the same choosing 6 heart then 5 diamond.

Yet, you are counting these as two **different** choices.

Comment: @David: You're welcome :)

Comment: An easier way to compute it is to ask what the odds are that the 2nd card is a different rank than the 1st . After the 1st card is picked there are 51 left , of which 48 are a different rank than the 1st card. So the odds are $48/51, $ which is equal to  $(4)(13)(4)(12)/(52\cdot 51).$.............+1

Comment: @user254665: This is already shown in the question itself.